# How to prevent a memory leak when displaying an image by binding to a bytearray?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, arrays

I have large treeview full of textboxes, each with tooltip containing a unique image. The image is stored in a property as a bytearray and I bind to it.  Every time a new tooltip is displayed more memory is used.

I will be scaling the image, but that doesn't address the root of the problem.  If there a way to free the memory used after the tooltip is no longer displayed?

```
<TextBlock.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image MaxWidth="650"
               MaxHeight="400"
               Source="{Binding ImageAsByteArray}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilePath, StringFormat='Full Path: {0}'}" />
    </StackPanel>
</TextBlock.ToolTip>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip can be set to any framework element, so could dynamically create this as an object behind the scenes:

```
<TextBlock ToolTip={Binding ToolTip} />
```

Then your view model or code behind could dynamically create this object and handle the loaded/unloaded event to capture when the tooltip displays.

I've done it below with a canvas is case you want to add other children besides the image:

```
var tooltipCanvas = new Canvas();
var img = new Image();

tooltipCanvas.Children.Add(img);
tooltipCanvas.Width = 500;
tooltipCanvas.Height = 500;
tooltipCanvas.Loaded += Tooltip_Loaded;
tooltipCanvas.Unloaded += Tooltip_Unloaded;
```

Then you could populate the image source just for the time the image is shown using the loaded and unloaded event handlers:

```
private void Tooltip_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = sender as Canvas;
    var img = canvas.Children[0] as Image;
    img.Source = /* get your image bytes */;
}

private void Tooltip_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = sender as Canvas;
    var img = canvas.Children[0] as Image;
    img.Source = null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? When I do this I can't get the memory to release.  I bind to the bytearray in XAML, catch the event for the canvas being unloaded, and cast the child to an image successfully. Setting the source to null does not free the memory. I also tried BindingOperations.ClearBinding with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure the memory doesn't release after a minute once garbage collection has occurred?  You could use a memory profiler to prove this - or (just for diags only) force a GC.Collect operation to prove whether it frees the memory ...

Comment: For testing I'm forcing a GC.Collect after I set the image source to null. The memory usage continues climbing as more tooltips are opened/closed.

Comment: You probably need to use a memory profiler e.g. ANTS to snapshot the memory before and after some tooltips have been opened and trace the retention graphs showing what is holding onto the memory.